# XSL - applying sum for 2 columns with different keys keeping all values

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

using saxon and xsl 2.0 .

the source is a sql query, but the input should be something like:

```
<//ROW> 
  <ROW[1]> 
    <col1>1</col1>
    <col2>a</col2>
    <col3>1</col3>
    <col4>a</col4>
  </ROW[1]> 
  <ROW[2]> 
    <col1>2</col1>
    <col2>a</col2>
    <col3>2</col3>
    <col4>a</col4>
  </ROW[2]> 
  <ROW[3]> 
    <col1>3</col1>
    <col2>b</col2>
    <col3>3</col3>
    <col4>b</col4>
  </ROW[3]> 
  <ROW[4]> 
    <col1>6</col1>
    <col2>b</col2>
    <col3>2</col3>
    <col4>a</col4>
  </ROW[4]> 
  <ROW[5]> 
    <col1>1</col1>
    <col2>d</col2>
    <col3>2</col3>
    <col4>a</col4>
  </ROW[5]> 
  <ROW[6]> 
    <col1>6</col1>
    <col2>b</col2>
    <col3>8</col3>
    <col4>c</col4>
  </ROW[6]> 
</ //ROW>
```

the xsl:

```
<xsl:key name="col4_key" match="//ROW" use="col4">
<xsl:template name = "totals">
  <xsl:for-each-group select = "//ROW" group-by="col2">
    <xsl:variable name="group_total">
      <xsl:value-of select="'./col2'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/col1)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'current-grouping-key()'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('col4_key', current-grouping-key())/col3)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#013;&#010;'"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

gives the result:

```
a;  3;  a;  7;
b;  15; b;  3;
d;  1;  d;  0;
```

i'm looking to get the c value too, like:

```
a;  3;  a;  7;
b;  15; b;  3;
d;  1;  d;  0;
c;  0;  c;  8;
```

my apologies if the questions is trivial, but what would be the way to apply grouping here to get the desired sums? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
<xsl:variable name="rows" select="//ROW"/>
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(($rows/(col2, col4)))" expand-text="yes">
   <xsl:variable name="key" select="."/>
   <xsl:text>{$key}; {sum($rows[col2=$key]/col1])}; {$key}; {sum($rows[col4=$key]/col3])};&#xa;</xsl:text> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you want an additional grouping for items not referenced earlier e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="col2_key" match="ROW" use="col2"/>

<xsl:for-each-group select="//ROW[not(key('col2_key', col4))]" group-by="col4">
  <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), sum(current-group()/col3)" separator="; "/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This gives the two values e.g. `c` and 8, I haven't quite understood where the other columns come from.